# Linux user-space scheduling while shutdown or reboot

Tags: linux-kernel

```
 68 void kernel_restart_prepare(char *cmd)
 69 {
 70         blocking_notifier_call_chain(&reboot_notifier_list, SYS_RESTART, cmd);
 71         system_state = SYSTEM_RESTART;
 72         usermodehelper_disable();
 73         device_shutdown();
 74 }
```

I am checking the linux kernel source `linux/kernel/reboot.c`.
Upon reboot call, the function defined above is called. 
My question is related to rebooting of the system. Since we are installing a reboot notifier in the driver, we want to be sure that our user-space process does not get called, while reboot is in progress.

1. If reboot is called, will the user-space processes still be running?
2. Is it guaranteed that if reboot notifier is called, the user-space process can still be running or scheduled?
3. Is the behavior guaranteed also on SMP, that user-space does not execute if reboot is called?
4. Can this call be pre-empted?
5. If driver registers to reboot-notifier list will it satisfy the requirement, that user-space applications do not execute at this notifier is called?
6. Is it possible to add a hook to `device_shutdown` in the driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kernel_restart_prepare` is called as part of `reboot` system call, which description [explicitely says](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/reboot.c#L278):

> reboot doesn't sync: do that yourself before calling this.

So there is no garantee that user-space processes will be finished at that moment, and it doesn't prevent new user-space processes to be started.

The function is run in standard kernel's environment, so it can be pre-empted as usual.

According to device_shutdown [implementation](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/base/core.c#L2041), it doesn't provide hook mechanism. It just calls `shutdown` method for every driver.